# LINQ multiple group by, how to fill in dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm trying to retrieve a dataset from RavenDB, group it by several categories and then store it per group in a dictionary. The retrieval and groupby have been solved. However, I'm stuck on how to put the combined group (group on 4 variables) into a dictionary. So in other words: the dictionary needs to be filled with each distinct name/year/month/day combination. I need this to later on display it in a graph - that part is already covered.

```
Dictionary<string, int> chartInformation = new Dictionary<string, int>();
List<string> xAxisCategories = new List<string>();

if (model.Period.Value == Timespan.Day)
{
    var groupedRecords = transformedRecords.GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.Name, 
        x.DateTo.Value.Year, 
        x.DateTo.Value.Month, 
        x.DateTo.Value.Day
    });

    foreach (var recordGroup in groupedRecords)
    {

        if (!chartInformation.ContainsKey(recordGroup.Key.Name, 
            recordGroup.Key.Year, recordGroup.Key.Month, recordGroup.Key.Day)) 
        // how to do this properly 
        {
            chartInformation.Add(recordGroup.Key.?, 0);
        }

        if (!xAxisCategories.Contains(recordGroup.Key.?))
        {
            xAxisCategories.Add(recordGroup.Key.?);
        }

        foreach (var record in recordGroup)
        {
            //filling stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect your key to be... you're trying to use a `query` property which doesn't exist in your `Add` call, and in your `ContainsKey` call you're trying to pass four arguments...

Comment: @JonSkeet the 'query' is old code, I'll remove that. The thing I'm trying to accomplish as said is fill the dictionary with unique combinations of `name-year-month-day`. However, the `ContainsKey` method only supports checking per variable, instead of on a combination of all 4.

Comment: It's still not query what you mean. An entry has a *single* value as the key. Currently you've declared the dictionary to have a string key... so you need to work out what the string should be. If you want it to be `name-year-month-day` you'll need to do some string formatting to obtain that.

Comment: @jonSkeet and my question is how to do that formatting.

Comment: Well that's extremely unclear from your post... in particular, you haven't specified anywhere what you'd want the format to be. It's not clear why you need it by string anyway, to be honest...

Comment: @JonSkeet "So in other words: the dictionary needs to be filled with each distinct name/year/month/day combination. I need this to later on display it in a graph - that part is already covered." I don't necessarily need it to be a string, but that example got handed to me and it worked.

Comment: That's not the same as saying "I need to populate it with a string key in this (sample) format." It's still not clear to me why you're not using the anonymous type - or potentially a named type - as the key here. What's the benefit of it being a key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61837/discussion-between-chrotenise-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to project your group key to a string like this:

```
var groupedRecords = transformedRecords.GroupBy(x => String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",
    x.Name, 
    x.DateTo.Value.Year, 
    x.DateTo.Value.Month, 
    x.DateTo.Value.Day));
```

Then you can iterate over the groups and check for existence of a certain key in your dictionary:

```
foreach(var group in groupedRecords)
{
    if(!chartInformation.ContainsKey(group.Key))
    {
        chartInformation.Add(group.Key, 0)
    }
}
```

However, keep in mind that **projecting your key to a string as shown above can lead to collisions**, i.e. rows that belong to different groups may end up in the same group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you explain these collisions further?

Comment: @Chrotenise, it dependends mostly on what the property `Name` contains. E.g. if you have two names `A` and `a` and the same date (let's say `Today`) then those entities will be sent to two different groups `A-2014-09-24` and `a-2014-09-24`. You should decide whether that's a good thing or a bad thing.

Comment: the name are category names for absences like holiday, sickness, etc. Each record will have a category it falls under and a date, so in this case it is oke if I have two records for the same timespan with different categories, to both be saved under a different category. I've edited your answer in the last loop to fix a typo and keep it like my old code.